# mbsync authentication failed

Tags: authentication, email, mbsync

I was able to configure mbsync and mu4e in order to use my gmail account (so far everything works fine). I am now in the process of using mu4e-context to control multiple accounts. 
I cannot retrieve emails from my openmailbox account whereas I receive this error

```
Reading configuration file .mbsyncrc
Channel ombx
Opening master ombx-remote...
Resolving imap.ombx.io... ok
Connecting to imap.ombx.io (*.*.10*.16*:*9*)... 
Opening slave ombx-local...
Connection is now encrypted
Logging in...
IMAP command 'LOGIN <user> <pass>' returned an error: NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
```

In other posts I've seen people suggesting AuthMechs Login or PLAIN but mbsync doesn't recognizes the command. Here is my .mbsyncrc file

```
IMAPAccount openmailbox
Host imap.ombx.io
User user@openmailbox.org
UseIMAPS yes
# AuthMechs LOGIN
RequireSSl yes
PassCmd "echo ${PASSWORD:-$(gpg2 --no-tty -qd ~/.authinfo.gpg | sed -n 's,^machine imap.ombx.io .*password \\([^ ]*\\).*,\\1,p')}"

IMAPStore ombx-remote
Account openmailbox

MaildirStore ombx-local
Path ~/Mail/user@openmailbox.org/
Inbox ~/Mail/user@openmailbox.org/Inbox/

Channel ombx
Master :ombx-remote:
Slave :ombx-local:
# Exclude everything under the internal [Gmail] folder, except the interesting folders
Patterns *
Create Slave
Expunge Both
Sync All
SyncState *
```

I am using Linux Mint and my isync is version 1.1.2
Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT: I have run a debug option and I have upgraded isync to version 1.2.1
This is what the debug returned:

```
Reading configuration file .mbsyncrc
Channel ombx
Opening master store ombx-remote...
Resolving imap.ombx.io... ok
Connecting to imap.ombx.io (*.*.10*.16*:*9*)... 
Opening slave store ombx-local...
pattern '*' (effective '*'): Path, no INBOX
got mailbox list from slave:
Connection is now encrypted
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Openmailbox is ready to
  handle your requests.
Logging in...
Authenticating with SASL mechanism PLAIN...
>>> 1 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN <authdata>
1 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
IMAP command 'AUTHENTICATE PLAIN <authdata>' returned an error: NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
```

My .msyncrc file now contains these options instead

```
SSLType IMAPS
SSLVersions TLSv1.2
AuthMechs PLAIN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end, the solution was to use the correct password. Since openmailbox uses an application password for third-party e-mail clients I was using the wrong (original) password instead of the application password.